# Remove ouline on PrimeNG checkbox

Tags: css, sass, primeng

I would like to remove the glow, a.k.a outline, of the PrimeNG checkbox component. (I know, I know. It's for accessability and all, but I'm implementing this indicator myself)

I've tried to set every thinkable class or selector to `outline: none`, and even the big bang approach with

```
*:focus {
  outline: none !important;
}
```

But nothing seems to work...

What do I need to do to get rid of it?

Thanks!

Edit, My angular-cli.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "test"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.sass",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "sass",
    "class": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

And at the top of my styles.sass I import my primeng.scss file:

```
@import 'primeng'
```

Comment: are you using a theme? can you post your angular-cli.json as well

Comment: I'm using the Omega theme as a base and restyling the components from this.

Comment: are you styling at the component level or from theme level?

Comment: Theme level. I have a copy of the Omega theme next to my styles.sass file.

Comment: please post your angular-cli.json

Comment: ok, It's added to the post

Comment: Bad tagging, please read what all the tags are about and remove the one you don't use

Comment: I don't see a theme file in there... did you copy the theme file contents into styles.sass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the omege theme.scss line 242 you will see:

```
.ui-chkbox-box.ui-state-focus,
.ui-radiobutton-box.ui-state-focus  {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #1f89ce;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #1f89ce;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #1f89ce;
 }
```

This is the style giving the checkbox the glow. You can set those properties to none to stop this.

```
.ui-chkbox-box.ui-state-focus,
.ui-radiobutton-box.ui-state-focus  {
   -moz-box-shadow: none;
   -webkit-box-shadow: none;
   box-shadow: none;
 }
```

If you don't want to edit the theme file you can override the css by doing something like:

```
.ui-chkbox-box.ui-state-focus {
   -moz-box-shadow: none;
   -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

The example above also includes radio buttons. Just reformat the css to exclude it: .ui-radiobutton-box.ui-state-focus

Comment: Aaah, of course! Thanks so much. I was going crazy over this. =)

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me

```
:host ::ng-deep .p-checkbox:not(.p-checkbox-disabled) .p-checkbox-box.p-focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```